# clearcase findmerge supress new element/directory

Tags: cleartool

I have two views say `A` and `B`,

```
c:\a_view
A - View
-------Folder_1-->test.bat
-------Folder_2
-------Folder_3

d:\b_view
B - View
-------Folder_1
-------Folder_2
```

When I do `findmerge` (with merge option):

```
c:\>cleartool findmerge "d:\b_view" -ftag a_view -type d -merge
```

I am getting output as:

```
d:\b_view
B - View
-------Folder_1-->test.bat(Merged file)
-------Folder_2
-------Folder_3 (Merged directory)
```

which is ok as per `findmerge` behavious,

But I want to merge only existing folder, i.e `Folder_1` should be only merged and new
elements `Folder_3` should be suppressed (should not be merged)

How can we do this?

---

```
cd D:\bView\Folder1
cleartool findmerge . -ftag a_view -type d -merge
```

This is fine, but suppose I have "n" number of folders I have to execute this command "N" times, it would take lot of time,

My requirement is only run on parent folder.

```
i.e
c:\>cleartool findmerge "d:\b_view" -ftag a_view -type d -merge
```

and it should exclude the new elements/folders

Do we have any parameter or some regular expression or some thing, which would exclude the new elements ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please leave your questions in the questions section. The answer section is reserved for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply go to Folder1 (in the destination view, that is the view where the merge takes place), and run the findmerge from there.

```
cd D:\bView\Folder1
cleartool findmerge . -ftag a_view -type d -merge
```

That would limit the merge to that specific folder (you find similar example in the [`cleartool findmerge` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm), since you can [merge directory versions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_bcc_mrgdrctyver.htm)).

> Do we have any parameter or some regular expression or some thing, which would exclude the new elements ?

The only thing you have would be the `NEVER_MERGE` type presented in this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123371):

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123371&aid=4]

But that is not practical to apply on all the folder (and their content).

You can also try a merge -ndata on the elements you don't want to merge (by making ClearCase think they are already merged).
Again, not practical.

It is best to list the high-level folders you want to merge and merge them individually.

Answer (score 0):

cd D:\bView\Folder1 cleartool findmerge . -ftag a_view -type d -merge

This is fine, but suppose I have "n" number of folders I have to execute this command "N" times, it would take lot of time,

My requirement is only run on parent folder.

i.e
c:>cleartool findmerge "d:\b_view" -ftag a_view -type d -merge
and it should exclude the new elements/folders

Do we have any parameter or some regular expression or some thing, which would exclude the new elements ?

Comment: Please delete this "answer" which is actually a question. I have restored your additional question in your... question.