# how to merge new folder from a sub branch to the main branch in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

How can I merge a newly created folder in a sub branch to the main branch?

I went to the version tree and did create merge by drawing.

But it still I cannot see the folder in main branch and the version on main branch is 0.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging only the folder (by drawing a red arrow between the version of the folder and the destination branch) is not enough.

That new folder has been introduced in a parent folder, which needs to be merged as well. That is what would allow you see to see that folder in the destination view.

It is best to go to the parent folder in the destination view (the one set to create version on the destination branch) and do a `findmerge` from there.
See this [`cleartool findmerge` question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20949762/6309).

```
cd D:\bView\Folder1
cleartool findmerge . -ftag a_view -merge
```

Comment: Hi, I have drawn the merge arrow for the parent folder as well, even though I can see the new folder in the main branch, I cannot see the file elements in the folder on main branch. Why could this be happening?

Comment: @user3437212 because the file elements needs also to be merged. Hence the findmerge, which does all that recursively for you.