# Clear Case Merging

Tags: merge, clearcase

I have merged the code from project/sub branch to main branch using version tree. I can see the merge arrow drawn from version at source branch to the version at destination branch.
[image]

But when I change my config spec to default config spec I can't see the folder on main branch and it still pointing to project branch.

Could you please let us know who to make it visible on main branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't see the folder on main branch and it still pointing to project branch.

- check your config spec (it should include only element * /main/LATEST)
- check that, as [I explained before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29677919/6309), the parent folder of the code that you have merged is *also* merged (also with a red arrow between `project_brnch` and `main`), or you wouldn't be able to see the merged code in `/main`.