# not able to see activities to deliver in clearcase ucm

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I had to deliver some code(a folder and some files inside) from an activity A from dev stream to int stream in ucm clearcase. before delivering I renamed the folder using another activity B and changed some files inside. Now, While delivering from dev to int, I cannot find A and B as undelivered work.

Please advise how to resolve. let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual workaround would be to a non-UCM merge by activity, instead of an UCM deliver (which is not listing the expected activities), using [`cleartool findmerge`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm).

See "[How to merge changes from a specific UCM activity from one ClearCase stream to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697198/6309)"

```
cd /path/to/myView/myFolder
ct findmerge activity:B@\pvob -fcsets -c "deliver B" -merge -gmerge
```

See also "[how to merge new folder from a sub branch to the main branch in clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29677919/6309)".

Comment: thanks. I know I can use non-ucm merge. But, I could not find out why this is happening. but thanks again for the help and the links

Comment: @user2636464 What is your version of ClearCase? Can you list activities on that stream to check A and B are still there? Can you ct descr -l those two activities?

Comment: clearcase 8.0. I can see both activities there. for a workaround I have just merged folders and files manually. But, I have not been able to find the reason why.